# Hiding Content Under Transparent Div (Pure CSS)?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to "shape" divs by using a div over the other div in order to hide parts of it. I am posting my code below.

Is there a pure CSS way to hide certain elements under a div without hiding the background in a transparent div?

In my example, I would like for the circle to be fully transparent (it's semi-transparent for easier visual purposes) and to hide the part of the square it overlaps.

```css
.square {
    background: rgba(134,95,96,1.00);
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20%;
    right: 20%;
    min-height: 500px;
    min-width: 500px;
}

.circle {
    background: rgba(141,76,147,0.50);
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 20%;
    right: 33%;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"><p>Square</p></div>
<div class="circle"><p>Circle</p></div>
```

Comment: Any reason you can't just make the circle color the background color? If it "looks" right, it is right :P

Comment: The background on the project is a video, so no, that's not exactly an option.

Comment: maybe look at clip path ?

Comment: I did, but I was hoping for a simpler solution. It's not supported on older browsers either, so that's another issue.